# Go ahead only if (condition)

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have this code

```
spinRoullete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (errors()){
             something 
               return;}
            if (!errors()){
               something else}
```

And this is for errors

```
 private boolean errors() {
    if (Rone.isChecked()) {
        if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr1.setError("");
        } else {
            nr1.setError(null);
        }
    }           if (Rtwo.isChecked()) {
        if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr1.setError("");
        } else {
            nr1.setError(null);
        }
        if (nr2.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr2.setError("");
        } else {
            nr2.setError(null);
        }
    }
```

Something here it's wrong and I don't know what .. The texterrors appears, and disappear when I complete the nr1, or nr2 (edittexts) but something it's wrong with the second if from onClick. When the errors disappear I want to go forward to that second if ( that with something else).. What should I edit to do this?

Comment: is it possible that both check `Rone.isChecked()` and `Rtwo.isChecked()` ?

Comment: No, you can't . And if errors appear you can't go forward.

Comment: Why do you need the second `if` at all? When you reach this position in the code you know already there are no errors otherwise you would have executed the `return` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, minor optimization improvement: You have this code (formatted for improved readability, same code):

```
if (errors()){
     something...
     return;
}
if (!errors()){
   something else...
}
```

But you don't need that least one since you have a return statement:

```
if(errors()){
    something
    return;
}

something else...
```

The method is called once instead of twice if there isn't an error, so you avoid problems there.

But you never return any visible value from errors(). Most likely, you have `return true` at the bottom, meaning it always goes into the first if statement. Simply change the method:

```
private boolean errors() {
    boolean i1 = false;//if no errors, return false
    if (Rone.isChecked()) {
        if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr1.setError("");
            i1 = true;//There is at least one error
        } else {
            nr1.setError(null);
        }
    }           
    if (Rtwo.isChecked()) {
        if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr1.setError("");
            i1 = true;//there is at least one error
        } else {
            nr1.setError(null);
        }
        if (nr2.getText().length() == 0) {
            nr2.setError("");
            return true;//This is the last thing that can happen, so just return true. There is at least one error, this one
        } else {
            nr2.setError(null);
            return i1;//there could have been an error earlier, so return i1
        }
    }
    return i1;//and if the last box isn't checked, return i1 here
}
```

Most likely, you have `return true` at the bottom of the method. That means it will always go into the first if-statement and return even if there are no errors.

---

And you should really start looking into indentation conventions, some of the code you posted is very hard to read because of that

Comment: Thx you, it's work fine. I will remember your answer

Comment: Nice Solution given @zoe